# how to extract the part of filename

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

i have a file name in below pattern and i want extract middle portion of the file.(i.e 20170217154436). how do I do this in c# (or script task)?

```
20170123-100046_20170217154436_A20170217210502
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: does it always has this format?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex, but I think you can also proceed like this:

```
String filename = "20170123-100046_20170217154436_A20170217210502";
String partToExtract = filename.Split('_')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the consistency of the format of the filename that you're using. I'll assume that, given your example `########-######_##############_@##############` is the format of your filename.

In your case, this should be suitable and avoids using arrays.

```
String fileName = "20170123-100046_20170217154436_A20170217210502";
fileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("_") - 1);
```

This takes a substring between the 0th element and the index of the last character before an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to get s string between the two characters: `_` and `_`

```
string myStr= "20170123-100046_20170217154436_A20170217210502";
Regex r = new Regex(@"_(.+?)_");
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(myStr);
Console.WriteLine("Fine name is " + mc[0].Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated Regex is an option but since it is not the most readable standard I would go with something clearer and more robust such as:

```
const char  splitChar = '_';

String fileName = "20170123-100046_20170217154436_A20170217210502";
int valueIndexStart = fileName.IndexOf(splitChar);
int valueIndexEnd = fileName.LastIndexOf(splitChar);


if(valueIndexStart != -1 && valueIndexEnd != -1)
{
    //increment so as to trip splitChar from result
    valueIndexStart++;
    valueIndexEnd = valueIndexEnd-valueIndexStart;
    return fileName.Substring(valueIndexStart, valueIndexEnd);
}else{
    //throw exception?
}
```

Of course you need to consider how standard this format is. You say the middle portion is what you are looking for, will there always be 3 portions? What happens if you find more or less separator characters? Can this character ever be within a value character. I'll leave that up to you on how to handle potential false positive or negatives though.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all your replies.
i tried something like below and it worked.

```
String fileName = "20170123-100046_20170217154436_A20170217210502";
fileName = filename.Substring(filename.IndexOf("_") + 1);
string fname;
fname=fileName.Substring(0, fileName .IndexOf("_"))
```

this gives me "20170217154436".